# Spring Boot RestEndpoint Redirect to Angular Route

Tags: spring, angular, spring-boot

I have a cross domain page, From there i will be getting the parameters needed to load the Angular UI.

The idea for me is to call the spring boot rest end point and redirect to angular page with response.

The spring boot rest end point with @PathVariable parameters, This will query the database and get the response, Once the response is ready which has to be redirected to angular route with the response.

I have used RedirectView to redirect but i am unable to get hold of the parameters in the Angular side. Just wondering what would be the best approach to pass the data in spring boot and intercept that on Angular side.

Comment: why don't you call the angular page first and use a route resolver to get the data from the rest api?

Comment: I need to pass the data from another application while clicking the hyperlink to spring+angular app.

Comment: Yes? So if your angular route is like example.com/product/16 then your resolver can do the data call while routing. (eg in the example, do the call to get the data for product with id 16.) That's what [route resolvers](https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-pre-fetching-component-data) are for.

Comment: Right now i am not that familiar on Route resolvers will check on that, however i am loading a route based on the incoming data, So based on my understanding, The other application will directly call the angular route url or construct the url dynamically, By which has the route resolver get the url and pass on to back end and render the page.Is that right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good practice to call the angular page first and use a route resolver to get the data from the rest API.

But in your case, you can redirect to an angular app from spring boot controller

```
 return "redirect:" + yourDomain/param1/param2
```

And route resolver in an angular app URL like

```
url: "/endUrl/:param1/:param2"
```

Read that parameter in the controller from state param

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I am able to achieve both with the combination of Spring boot Rest Endpoint and Angular Route Resolver.

```
 @GetMapping(value = "/list/{param1}/{param2}")
public RedirectView redirectToHomePage(final RedirectAttributes attributes, @PathVariable final String param1,
    @PathVariable final String param2)
{
    return new RedirectView("/showlist/{param1}/{param2}", true);
}
```

On the Angular Side

```js
@Injectable()
export class ShowlistResolver implements Resolve<any> {

  private data: UserData

  constructor(private router: Router, private userService: UserService) {
    this.userData = new UserData();
  }

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): any {
    console.log('In Router')
    this.userData.userId = route.params['id']
    this.userData.userRole = route.params['role'];
    this.userService.setUserData(this.userData);
    this.router.navigate(['/showAll/list', {outlets: {details: ['showDetails']}}]);
  }
```